# How to get model data from PostAsync?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have just start some R&D on integrating an MVC application that calls a WebApi, both of which I am writing. The WebApi will be called by different applications eventually so I want to have to business logic in here.

I have created the following simple method on my API server:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(ShipmentGetCarrierModel view)
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse<ShipmentGetCarrierModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, view);
    return response;

    //return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I am calling this method from my MVC application as follows:

```
public ActionResult GetOrderNumber2(int orderNumber)
{
    using (var apiServer = new HttpClient())
    {
        apiServer.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52126");
        apiServer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        apiServer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ShipmentGetCarrierModel model = new ShipmentGetCarrierModel();
        model.nOrderNumber = 100;

        // New code:
        HttpResponseMessage response =
            apiServer.PostAsync("api/PC/Get",
            model,
        new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return Content(response.Content.ToString());
        }
    }

    return Content("NOT  " + orderNumber.ToString());
}
```

My model which is identical for both applications is:

```
public class ShipmentGetCarrierModel
{
    public int nID { get; set; }
    public int nOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeName { get; set; }
    public string cCarrierCode { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeCity { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeProvince { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneePostalCode { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeTelephone { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeContact { get; set; }
    public string cConsigneeCountry { get; set; }
    public Boolean? lIsPharmilink { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the response code but I cannot see the model data that is returned in the debugger that is created by the WebAPI.

Ironically when I analyse the call using Fiddler, I see my model with their null values.

[image: Fiddler Image]

Obviously I am missing something here.
TIA
Mark

Comment: "I cannot see the model data" Where do you expect to see it but it's not there?

Comment: Maybe you should consider returning a JsonResult eg :
return Json(view, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: I just added the model code above.

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered what I was doing wrong; I missed two steps after calling the HttpClient

```
public ActionResult GetOrderNumber2(int orderNumber)
{
    using (var apiServer = new HttpClient())
    {
        apiServer.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52126");
        apiServer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        apiServer.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ShipmentGetCarrierModel model = new ShipmentGetCarrierModel();
        model.nOrderNumber = 100;

        // New code:
        HttpResponseMessage response =
            apiServer.PostAsync("api/CPC/Get",
            model,
        new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;

        // I was missing this !!!
        string returnResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JavaScriptSerializer JSserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ShipmentGetCarrierModel returnModel = JSserializer.Deserialize<ShipmentGetCarrierModel>(returnResult);


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return Content(returnModel.ToString());
        }
    }

    return Content("NOT  " + orderNumber.ToString());
}
```